# PHP - Why do different versions of PHP return different results when I use $this as a dynamic variable in isset()?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.1, php-7.0

In PHP 7.0:

```
$a = 'this';
return isset( $$a );
// returns true
```

But in PHP 7.1:

```
$a = 'this';
return isset( $$a );
// returns false
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Really? https://3v4l.org/ARNhT

Comment: @Andreas yes, and the PHP version I used was 7.0.8

Comment: But you see this? *Output for 5.6.30, hhvm-3.18.5 - 3.22.0, 7.0.30 - 7.3.0alpha1*?

Comment: @Andreas, the question probably means something like https://3v4l.org/kQ271.

Comment: And for comparison: https://3v4l.org/RDJa0

Comment: @jh1711 yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to this change in 7.1:

> #### Inconsistency fixes to `$this`
>
> Whilst `$this` is considered a special variable in PHP, it lacked
>   proper checks to ensure it wasn't used as a variable name or
>   reassigned. This has now been rectified to ensure that `$this` cannot
>   be a user-defined variable, reassigned to a different value, or be
>   globalised.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php#migration71.other-changes.inconsistency-fixes-to-this

[This RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/this_var) explains it in more detail, though it also says:

> #### Disable ability to re-assign `$this` indirectly through `$$`
>
> An attempt to re-assign `$this` through `$$` assignment will lead to
>   throwing of Error exception.
>
> ```
> $a = "this";
> $$a = 42; // throw new Error("Cannot re-assign $this")
> ```
>
> *It's still possible to read `$this` value through `$$`.*

(Emphasis mine.)

`isset` seems to have its own special treatment of `$$` for `$this` which prohibits it from seeing it. I'm not sure if that's intentional or a byproduct of these changes.